# Recorrer una lista y que te devuelva tantos asteriscos como indique el numero introducido

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un ejercicio en el que me pide crear un "Histograma" a partir de los datos introducidos por teclado y que se guardan en una lista python.

Por ejemplo, introduzco por teclado unos números y se añaden a una lista python: `lista[4, 9, 7]`. El prompt me debe mostrar lo siguiente:

```
****
*********
*******
```

De momento tengo hecho este código, pero no sé en qué falla:

```
lista=[]
v=0

def procedimiento(num):
    for i in range(num): 
        print("*",end=" ")


while v!=4:
    num=int(input("Introduce num astericos para histograma: "))
    lista.append(num)
    v=v+1


    procedimiento(num)
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas llamando a tu función encargada de imprimir el histograma (si no es un error de identado al pegar el código) en cada iteración del `while`, por lo que mezclas la impresión con los inputs y sin un salto de línea entre ellos (`end = " "`). Deberías primero guardar los números en la lista como haces y al terminar iterar sobre la lista o mandar directamente la lista a la función `procedimiento`.

Si el número de elementos a introducir están definidos antes del ciclo usa un `for` y no un `while`, es más eficiente y más "pythónico".

Para imprimir los asteriscos en vez de otro ciclo puedes hacer simplemente:

```
print("*" * num)
```

Por ejemplo, usando dos funciones separadas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
def imprimir_histograma(barras):
    for num in barras: 
        print("*" * num)

def ingresar_datos(n): 
    lista=[] 
    for _ in range(n):
        num = int(input("Introduce num astericos para histograma: "))
        lista.append(num)
    return lista

lista = ingresar_datos(3)
imprimir_histograma(lista)
```

Salida:

```
Introduce num astericos para histograma: 4
Introduce num astericos para histograma: 9
Introduce num astericos para histograma: 7
****
*********
*******
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa es aprovechar el hecho de que al multiplicar una cadena de texto por un entero, python lo que hace es repetir ese número de veces la cadena.

Por ejemplo este código sirve si el usuario ingresa los datos de la forma `4 9 7` (separados por espacios):

```
datos_histograma = input('Introduce num astericos para histograma: ') # recibe los datos
lista_histograma = [int(d) for d in datos_histograma.split()] # los convierte en int y los junta en una lista
for d in lista_histograma:
    print(d * '*') # repetir d veces el caracter '*'
```

Resultado:

```
Introduce num astericos para histograma: 4 7 9
****
*******
*********
```